# Text box at bottom right corner of table viewer , taking care of scroll bar visiblity / invisibility

Tags: java, swt

I want to get a small find text box exactly at the bottom right corner of `TableViewer`. ( with no space in bottom right corner borders of text box and table)

So, the size will be the same , but depending upon the visibility of Horizontal and Vertical Scroll bars, the position will change slightly.

But, right now , even if scroll bars are visible, `viewer.getTable().getHorizontaBar().isVisible()` is returning false, so is there any other way, so that I can know my textbox is getting hidden behind scrollbars.

Adding an image for clarification :-[image]

Comment: You mean you want to overlap a text box over the table, or just put it underneath the table? If you could provide more information on what you're trying to do, maybe we could give you UX advice too. I can imagine that what you're attempting here won't look very nice on the screen. You could even post some code, like an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Do you want to filter the `TableViewer`? If so, there are ways to do that: [Filtering data](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html#jfacetable_filter)

Comment: Even more tricky on a Mac where the scroll bars are not shown until you start scrolling when they appear, and then disappear again when you stop scrolling.

Comment: @GGrec Actually, I want to add small find text box, when I start typing or press CTRL+F, so yes... It will be better if I can put it underneath the table, so there will not be any issue regarding scroll bars visibility. Just relative to the position of table, I want to add small text box underneath the table.                    Or even overlapping small portion of scrollbars will do. As shown in the image.

Comment: Please note here, filtering is not my aim at all, I just want to highlight first matching entry, like quick find!